# RX - Run code only if subject meets criteria

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I'm using observables to handle keydown events.
I'd like to publish an observable, that will always set the key to handled **iff** the consumer has actually processed it. 
Is this possible?

Here's an example how I set keys handled now:

```
KeyDown.Where(e => e.Key == Keys.W)
.Subscribe(e => { Console.WriteLine(e.Key); e.Handled = true; });
```

Here's an example how I'd like to do it (if the handled property was automatically set afterwards, I could just publish Keys instead of KeyDownEventArgs too):

```
HandledKeyDown.Where(k => k == Keys.W).Subscribe(k => Console.WriteLine(k));
```

Here's what I tried:

```
HandledKeyDown = Observable.Create<Key>(observer => {
    var keys = KeyDown.Subscribe(e => { e.Handled = true; observer.OnNext(e.Key); });
    return () => keys.Dispose();
});
```

The issue with this code is that the key will always be set as handled, regardless whether the consumer actually processed it.

Is there a way to know if the code has "reached" the subscribe method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you'd like is to overload subscription on `KeyEventArgs` so that it makes an event as handled after the subscription. Sounds like an extension:

```
public static IDisposable SubscribeAndHandle(this IObservable<KeyEventArgs> input, Action<Keys> action)
{
    return input.Subscribe(e => { action(e.KeyCode); e.Handled = true; });
}
```

Then you just use `SubscribeAndHandle` instead of `Subscribe`, which will set `Handled` to true only after the action has been run, and the action can use `Keys` not `KeyEventArgs`:

```
var sub = KeyDown
          .Where(e => e.KeyCode = Keys.W) // and so on
          .SubscribeAndHandle(k => Console.WriteLine(k));
```

---

Note that you could use `Do` instead in the extension method if you don't mind that `Handled` is set to true before the action is performed. This is a cleaner way of running side effects:

```
public static IDisposable SubscribeAndHandle(this IObservable<KeyEventArgs> input, Action<Keys> action)
{
    return input.Do(e => e.Handled = true)
                .Select(e => e.KeyCode)
                .Subscribe(e => action(e));
}
```

---

A helpful comment from @Enigmativity suggested that perhaps you might like to decide whether `Handled` is set to true or not from within your subscription. This is simple enough, just change the extension method to accept a `Func<Keys,bool>` rather than an `Action<Keys>`:

```
public static IDisposable SubscribeAndHandle(this IObservable<KeyEventArgs> input, Func<Keys,bool> action)
{
    return input.Subscribe(e => e.Handled = action(e.KeyCode));
}
```

Comment: Your code forces the `e.Handled` property to be set to true. I understood that the OP wanted some logic to say that his consumer has actually processed it. You would need to change the signature of your action to be `Func<Keys, bool>` to facilitate that.

Comment: Yep, in my interpretation he just wants `Handled = true` whenever the subscriber has received and 'processed' the event, quoting "Is there a way to know if the code has "reached" the subscribe method?".  And he wants the subscriber to just receive the simple `Keys` rather than the more complex `KeyEventArgs`.

Comment: Yep. This does EXACTLY what I wanted (didn't even need the last part, you nailed it the first time). Don't know how I should have asked it, but guess it's my fault that 2 out of 3 people misinterpreted the question. Anyways, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at doing something like this:

```
var HandledKeyDown =
    KeyDown
        .Do(e => { /* Handling Code Here */ })
        .Where(e => e.Handled)
        .Where(e => e.Key == Keys.W)
        .Select(e => e.Key)
        .Subscribe(k => Console.WriteLine(k));
```

The `Do` extension method lets you "intercept" the value of an observable inline.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'd like to filter _HandledKeyDown_ with any criteria, not just filter for _W_. If I understand correctly, this command would make HandledKeyDown only able to process Ws. Do is nice to know about though, it'll make handling normal KeyDowns easier.

Comment: @user974608 - The filtering by `Keys.W` is only there because your code had that - it's not important as far as this solution goes. You only really need the `Do` and the first `Where` clause for my solution to work.

Comment: `Do` is run regardless of whether or not it reaches the subscription no? OP will this suffice if `Do` was moved down the observable chain to after the `Where` statements? If not, why not?

Comment: @yamen - The `.Where(e => e.Handled)` relies on the handling code to have occurred in the `.Do` so the `.Do` cannot be moved lower than it. The consuming code goes in the `.Do` statement and not the `.Subscribe`. Is that what the confusion is here?

Comment: I'm not sure this is what's being requested since `Do` is no different in this case to what `Subscribe` does in the original case. The OP wants `Handled` set after the subscription is run. See my answer - I imagine that's the target scenario.

Comment: @yamen - I've read the question again and I think my answer still makes sense. I read his question as he would like an observable that fires if and only if the consumer code handled the key press. In my answer the consumer code is in the `.Do`. What he chooses to do in the `.Subscribe` method has nothing to do with the handling of the key press.

Comment: I think I'll let the OP decide :-) Based on how he says "this is how I currently do it", I think he wants a framework for automatically setting `Handled` post subscription handling, with the convenience of subscription handling. I think he wanted the "consumer code" and the "subscribe" method to be the same thing (referencing your words). Anyway, fun deciphering!